# Monotone version of one-dimensional Whitney extension theorem

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

Is there a version of the [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) that would extend  a **monotone** $C^\infty$ function on a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ (satisfying the usual Whitney's compatibility conditions) to a **monotone** $C^\infty$ function defined on $\mathbb R$?

I very much hope for a reference. I did an extensive search with no success.

Comment: Did you find interesting references for the one dimensional version of the Whitney extension theorem? I am interested in any version, not necessarily $C^\infty$ or monotone.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: If memory serves I found a bypass that served my purpose. I think I needed "monotone" to eventually produce a diffeomorphism. The book review https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2016-53-01/S0273-0979-2015-01496-5/ contains all relevant references even though they may not consider monotone case.

Comment: I repeated a version of your question (https://mathoverflow.net/q/407655/121665) since I find it very interesting and closely related to problems I am working on now.